# AWS S3 Policy, Allow all resources and deny some

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

why this policy is not working? it allows all command on all resources but not deny on the selected folders! how can i resolve this kind of problem?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Banca",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Bilanci",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Bilanci/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Contenziosi",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Contenziosi/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi France/Affari societari",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi France/Affari societari/*",
            ]
        },
        {
          "Sid": "Stmt1595519755000",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:*"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage"
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by "not working"? What command was issued and what happened? The answer will depend on what command was used (eg `GetObject` vs `ListBucket`).

Comment: the posted policy permit to list and read all documents in all subfolder but i need to hide the resources in the deny part. Have you got some example where you can user allow all and deny some resources at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using `Deny`. (I did not test this!)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Banca/*",
                        "Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Bilanci/*",
                        "Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Contenziosi/*",
                        "Storage_WK/Agedi France/Affari societari/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Banca/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Bilanci/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi Monaco/Contenziosi/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::agdstorage/Storage_WK/Agedi France/Affari societari/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `ListBucket` is controlled via the `Prefix`, so it is simply using `StringNotLike`.

For `GetObject` and `PutObject`, it is using the resources you listed.

Comment: the correct syntax is StringNotLike but it works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBucket` command operates at the bucket-level, not at the object-level.

Here is an example of a policy that grants access only to a specific folder:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["David/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/David/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that `ListBucket` references the Bucket, but limits access by specifying a `Prefix`.

This is different to `GetObject` and `PutObject` that can be limited by providing a path in `Resource`.

To know how each command operates, consult [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html) and refer to the **Resource Types** column.

If possible, try to **avoid using `Deny`** since negative logic can sometimes be less obvious (just like this sentence). It is better to **only grant the desired permissions**, rather than granting *everything* and then denying some permissions. For example, the policy shown in your question actually grants permission to delete objects outside of the specified folders (eg at the root level) and to even delete the bucket itself (if it is empty).

If you are simply wanting to grant users access to their *own* folder, you can use [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This automatically adjusts the policy based upon the username of the user, so they can access folders based on their username.

Comment: It's quite impossible right now to only grant the desired permission because the bucket is full of subfolders and the user can create a new folder that needs to be accessible by default. Can you specify an example of allow all with some deny ? Thanks

Comment: FYI: I added an example of granting access to _personal folders_ for each user, based on their username.